# Add a component at the bottom of navigationOptions header of React-Native

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add a custom searchbar at the bottom of the navigationOptions header of react-native

Code:

```
  public static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: any) => {
    const { state: { params = {} } } = navigation
    return {
      headerBackground: (
        <Image
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg' }}
        />
      ),
      headerStyle: customStyle,
      headerTitle: (
        <Text>Title<Text/>
      ),
      headerLeft: <HamburgerMenu navigation={navigation} />,
      headerRight: (<View><Text>Test</Text></View>)
    }
  }
```

I want to add something similiar to headerBottom inside the header with same backgroundImage, not sure if the there is any property exists for bottom item, I am struggling to add a custom searchbar inside the header only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out to have different solution for it, rather placing the searchbar inside the navigationoption I placed it outside and used transparentHeader: 'true' to achieve my requirement.